# Getting null from array even when there are values in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have simple order system. When order is submit customer should have download button on his orders page. So far so good. The order details are displayed except one addition value which I see that it is in array.

This is how the array looks like

```
object(stdClass)#454 (3) {
  ["223"]=>
  object(stdClass)#453 (3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "test"
    ["price"]=>
    int(12)
    ["file_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["224"]=>
  object(stdClass)#451 (3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "test2"
    ["price"]=>
    int(1)
    ["file_id"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  ["shipping"]=>
  object(stdClass)#456 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(17) "Shipping Option 1"
    ["price"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

Objects `223` and `224` are the ID's of two products. On page I can see `title` and `price` for both products but `file_id` is NULL for them. This is how I'm displaying them

```
 @foreach($download->getOrderData($download->order_details) as $itemId => $item)
     <p>{{ $item->title }}</p>
     <p>{{ $item->price }}</p>
     <p>{{ $item->file_id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

This is the Order model

```
public function getOrderData($data)
{
    $dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($dataArray);
    $arrayKeys = array_filter($arrayKeys, function ($value) {
        return ($value !== 'shipping');
    });
    $productIds = implode(',', $arrayKeys);

    $products = DB::table('products')
        ->leftjoin('category', 'products.category_id', '=', 'category.category_id')
        ->leftjoin('sub_category', 'products.sub_cat_id', '=', 'sub_category.sub_cat_id')
        ->where('product_id', $productIds)
        ->get();

    foreach ($products as $item) {
        if (!in_array($item->product_id, $arrayKeys)) continue;
        $dataArray[$item->product_id]['category'] = $item->category_name;
        $dataArray[$item->product_id]['sub_category'] = $item->sub_cat_name;

    }
    return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the underscore is causing problems.
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables

Hence perhaps

```
{{ $item['file_id'] }}
```

Might do the trick.

Comment: Why twig? Laravel uses blade.

Comment: Getting the error `Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: @u_mulder sorry I just saw the {{ and thought it was twig - never used blade